# Set portrait only orientation on devices with a screen size of less than 7 inches

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-orientation

I am creating an android application that I want to:

- Run portrait only orientation on screen sizes (6.9"-)
- Run portrait and landscape orientations on screen sizes (7"+)

How would I declare this without using androids deprecated (small, normal, large, xlarge) screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store some Boolean in values folders. There can be multiple values folders like values-h720dp or values-w320dp. Then read those data in oncreated method of activity and then set proper orientation. To learn more read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)